# Fakes on OpenSea

Tags: solidity, nft, erc-721, opensea

Recently, our team faced a small problem. We made an announcement of the collection and showed several nfts. Soon, fakes of our collection and our profile appeared on OpenSea. How to resist this ? Verify the collection? Do a profile in advance? Thank you in advance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify the collection. You can't stop anyone from creating clones